# Find coordinates of points on circumference given segment height

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I have a circumference with radius $r$ and center in $O(cx, cy)$.

Then I know $h1$, $h2$ and $h3$ that are the distance from the top point to the points $a, b$, $g, f$ and $c, e$.
How can I find the coordinates $x$ and $y$ of $a, b, c, e, f, g$?

[image]

---

I try the idea of  **Alexey Burdin** obtaining:

```
gx = cx + r * cos(r / (r - h2))
gy = h2

fx = cx + r * cos(r / (r - h2))
fy = h2

cx = cx + r * cos(r / (r - h3))
cy = h3

ex = cx + r * cos(r / (r - h3))
ey = h3
```

but it seems not to work because points are not in the right position.

Comment: Basically you have $(x,y)=(c_x+r\cos t,c_y+r\sin t)$ then the equations will be, for $a,b$:$c_y+r\sin t=c_y+r-h_1$, for $g,f$: $c_y+r\sin t=c_y+r-h_2$, for $c,e$: $c_y+r\sin t=c_y+r-h_3$ from each equation you can find $t$ and hence the x-coordinate $x_c+r\cos t$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thanks for your answer but it seems not to work. I edit my main question with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x, y) = (x, c_y + r -h)$ are the coordinates of one of these points then
\begin{equation}
r^2=(x-c_x)^2 + (y-c_y)^2 = (x - c_x)^2+(r-h)^2
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
x = c_x\pm \sqrt{r^2 - (r-h)^2} = c_x\pm\sqrt{h(2r-h)}
\end{equation}