# Y coordinates of points on circumference given segment height and circle center coordinates

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

A month ago I've posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757397/find-coordinates-of-points-on-circumference-given-segment-height/3757549#3757549), now I realized that there are some problems with `y` coordinates.

This is the problem. I have a circle with center at `(cx, cy)` and the heights `hA`, `hB`, `hC`, `hD` of the circular segments `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.
I would like to find the coordinates of the points `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, ... , `k`.

[image]

The problem is the `y` coordinates of those points.
How can I compute them?

The user Gribouillis answers that a generic point on circumference has coordinates $(x, y) = (x, c_y + r - h)$ but I don't think that $c_y + r -h$ is right.

Comment: **algebraic-geometry** is not a correct tag for this question.  **analytic-geometry** would be more appropriate.

Comment: Done correcting the tag.

Comment: I think the $y$-coordinates are easy to compute just by observation. First we need the radius $R$:
$$
2R = h_D + h_C +h_B + h_A \quad \Rightarrow R = \frac{1}{2}(h_D + h_C +h_B + h_A)
$$
now, we just have to "travel" from the centre point to the desired location. For example the $y$-coordinate of point $e$ is obtained by
$$
y_e = c_y - R + h_D + h_C
$$
or, alternatively,
$$
y_e = c_y + R - h_A - h_B
$$
That's it!

Comment: His answer is correct for the problem you posted there. Your height was from the top of the circle (from the point where x-coordinates remained same as the center). So y coordinate of that point is $cy+r$ and then you subtract the height from there.